# Uninstalled system keyboard

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, keyboard, troubleshooting, samsung-galaxy-star

I rooted my phone and uninstalled keyboard application without  backup.. Now i removed my root. I need keyboard. My phone is galaxy star pro. Android version 4.1.2. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1) You can install gapps for your model if available. 
2) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jlsoft.inputmethod.latin.jelly.free 
3) http://google-keyboard.en.softonic.com/android

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've configured your device with a Google account, and have already used *Google Play Store* with it, the easiest way is to

1. visit *Google Play Store* via web browser from your PC
2. login with your account
3. select any keyboard app you like (e.g. the standard [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin))
4. trigger the installation from there.

Shortly thereafter you should see the installation starting on your device (provided it's connected to the internet, of course). Once that's finished, the keyboard should automatically be available.